# What is behind the external vent cover on the driver's side of a runabout boat?

Tags: boat

I was power washing my runabout boat today and sprayed over this vent.  What is behind the vent?  Is it OK to get it wet?

My boat is a Stingray, but this picture is from a Bayliner.

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about boats and fittings, not about motor vehicle (that is, *land* motor vehicle) maintenance and repair

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not motor vehicle maintenance or repair.

Comment: Mike/David - we have established that boats are on-topic here as long as the question is about maintenance or repair. The OP is asking about the risk of damage from water ingress, so IMHO that is relevant. If he were asking about fibreglassing the hull or repairing the rudder I'd agree with off-topic.

Comment: @NickC if it was engine or even engineering related ie shafts, bearings, tolerances etc I would agree. But some non-descript ventilation slot...

Comment: Is there a stack exchange community that is better suited for this question? I looked around but could not find one for marine.

Comment: Its a bilge vent and usually is connected to a vent fan that should be run for several minutes before starting the engine.

Comment: @Moab I thought the bilge vents were in the back next to the engine compartment on an Inboard/Outboard boat

Answer (score 0):

That's a bilge blower vent. There's a hose going from the engine bay to the vent with an electric air blower in the middle.

You can verify this by turning on the bilge blower and check if there is a small flow of air (and noise) from the vent.